# Arduino with A9 - troubleshooting AT commands

Tags: c, arduino, gsm

I am programming an Arduino with an A9 which has the ability to take AT commands directly. I'm using the following code, which allows me to enter commands:

```
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial1.begin(115200);
  pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(8,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(5, HIGH); 
  digitalWrite(4, LOW); 
  digitalWrite(8, HIGH); 
  delay(3000);       
  digitalWrite(8, LOW);
  Serial.println("A7 Power ON!"); 
}

void loop()
{
    char dat;
    if(Serial1.available()){
        dat = Serial1.read();
        Serial.print(dat);
    }
    if(Serial.available()){
        dat = Serial.read();
        Serial1.print(dat);  
    }
}
```

I can see that it's registered:

> AT+CREG?
>
> +CREG: 2,3,"A5FA","5CB4",0

and that it is in plaintext SMS mode:

> AT+CMGF=?
>
> +CMGF:(0,1)
>
> OK
>
> AT+CMGF=1
>
> OK

but attempts to send and receive messages get a CMS ERROR 500 and 300 respectively:

> AT+CMGS="0584413829"
>
> > test sms 
> >     +CMS ERROR: 500
>
> AT+CMGL="ALL"
>
> +CMS ERROR: 300

Anyone have any ideas? I'm at my wits' end.

Comment: Have you tried setting modem character set with `AT+CSCS = "GSM"`?

Comment: yes. Same issue.

Answer (score 0):

for the error 300 it means:

> Mobile equipment (ME) failure.

where Mobile equipment refers to the mobile
device that communicates with the wireless network

the 500 is an unknown error, did you break the GSM module maybe?

Comment: Doubtful-AT+CREG=? returns valid data, so it's registering, which requires both hearing and speaking with the GSM panel.